# TypeScript Problem with Adding New Property to react-leaflet Marker Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to pass an additional property `count` into the `Marker` component provided by `react-leaflet`.

However, we are getting an error

```
Type '{ children: Element; position: [number, number]; key: number; count: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MarkerProps & RefAttributes<Marker<any>>'.
  Property 'count' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MarkerProps & RefAttributes<Marker<any>>'.  TS2322
```

Is there a way to solve this? Is it possible to extend the current TS interface of `Marker`?

**React/TS Code:**

```
interface IMarker {
    lat: number;
    lon: number;
    count: number;
}

interface IProps {
    data: IMarker[];
}

const createClusterIcon = (cluster: any) => {
    const childMarkers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
    let childCount = 0;
    childMarkers.forEach((m:IMarker) => {
        childCount = childCount + m.options.count;
    });

    return L.divIcon({
        html: `<div><span>${childCount}</span></div>`,
        className: 'marker-cluster-small',
        iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40)
    })
}

export function MapView({data}: IProps): JSX.Element {
    // Combine markers in `data` array
    let markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        markers.push(...data[i]);
    }

    return (
        <MapContainer>
            <MarkerClusterGroup iconCreateFunction={createClusterIcon}>
                {
                    markers.map((marker, index) => (
                        <Marker 
                            position={[marker.lat, marker.lon]} 
                            key={index}
                            count={ marker.count }
                        />
                }
            </MarkerClusterGroup>  
        </MapContainer>  
    )
}
```

Comment: The Marker component doesn't have any prop called address, so even if you could pass it without error it wouldn't do anything. Why are you trying to pass it?

Comment: @Jayce444 I am trying to pass `count` into `Marker`, then use it as `Marker.option.count` from within `createClusterIcon()` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59154900/741099). Updated question to change `address` to `count`.

Comment: @Jayce444 This github link shows what I am trying to achieve, but using TypeScript and React: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/901#issuecomment-610723716

Answer (score 3):

You can create your "**own**" Marker component using method exported from the **core** package.
Check the implementation of the [Marker](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/packages/react-leaflet/src/Marker.tsx) component.
In other words copy the implementation of the Marker react component and change it.
For example this way:

```
export interface CustomMarkerProps extends MarkerOptions, EventedProps {
  children?: ReactNode;
  position: LatLngExpression;
  // custom object to be associated with a leaflet's marker
  customAttr: Object;
}

export const CustomMarker = createLayerComponent<LeafletMarker, CustomMarkerProps>(
  function createMarker({ customAttr, position, ...options }, ctx) {
    const instance = new LeafletMarker(position, options);
    // add customAttr to the leaflet's instance (leaflet, not the react wrapper)
    // @ts-ignore
    instance.customAttr = customAttr;
    return { instance, context: { ...ctx, overlayContainer: instance } };
  },
  function updateMarker(marker, props, prevProps) {
    // same as in the react-leaflet
  }
);
```

Later on you can access the leaflet's instance and retrive your customAttr.

Comment: Hello @palo ,
I am trying to use your suggestion from back then for my purposes. However, I get the error 
 `"Property 'customAttr' does not exist on type 'Marker<any>'." `

I have tinkering here and there but still I am kinda stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: I am not sure if I can. 

I used this approach almost 3 years ago with these versions: 
@react-leaflet/core": "1.0.2", "react-leaflet": "3.1.0", "leaflet": "1.7.1". 
The react-leaflet is now at version 4.2.1 and the Marker component has changed, so my recommendation may be outdated.

I have one suggestion though - try to add `// @ts-ignore` like in the updated example.
A new property is added into the LeafletMarker, so typescript error is not unexpected.

I think that's all I can say or suggest.